# how to attach footer div with footer border when i resize or increase the height of widget

Tags: jquery, html, css

How to attach footer div with footer border  when i resize or increase the height of widget.
The center content height will be automaticaly increased when resize as like when resize width.

```
    <div class="draggable" class="ui-widget-content" style="overflow:hidden;">
        <div class="widget_container">
            <div class="Widget_title"> widget head</div>
            <div class="clear_left"></div>
            <div class="widget_contents">
                <input type="text" class="idv" style="display:none" value=""/>
                <p>Drag me around</p>
            </div>
                <div class="clear_left"></div>

        </div>
        <div class="Widget_name">footer widget</div>
    </div>
```

[Example link](http://jsfiddle.net/vjbCJ/3/)

Comment: Please add code directly in the question. Boil it down to the minimum required to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Use `position:absolute;bottom:0;` in css with classname `Widget_name`. Increase bottom value to increase the gap.

Comment: In order to better understand this question you should provide your css, and even better would be a partial demo showing the issue using something like [jsfiddle.net](http://www.jsfiddle.net).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check out this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vjbCJ/4/..

```
.widget_container{
position: relative;
height:60%;

}

.Widget_title{
background-color: antiquewhite;
height: 30%;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
}
.Widget_name{
background-color: beige;
height: 33%;
}
```

to see if it what you are looking for...

Comment: can u also increase the widget_contents background